# Deleting stale google search results

Tags: web

I had hosted some pages on a google drive.  Since google no longer allows that, I moved the pages elsewhere and resubmitted a request for google to crawl them.

Unfortunately google still includes the old pages in search results.

Is there anyway to tell google to forget the old results?  Will they eventually disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's webmaster tools allows you to migrate a website from one domain to another, but I don't know in how far this applies to you.

(Ie, if the Google drive pages where reachable through a domain name you control or not.)

Otherwise, I'd say a bit of patience will do: if your Drive pages disappeared completely, they will disappear from the index eventually.